# Create a RichFaces JSF application on tomcat without using jboss app server

Tags: jsf, maven, richfaces

I know that RichFaces is maintained by JBOSS; what I'm trying to do is to add JSF/RicFaces to an existing maven based dynamic web project.

I would like to know if it is possible to use RichFaces without using JBOSS server? I'm using tomcat 6

What dependencies should I mention in my pom.xml?

Currently I've following in my POM, but I don't think that they are sufficient.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>           
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help will be great!

Comment: You have to add JSF dependency.

Comment: Where did you read that RichFaces requires JBoss AS? This is namely nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any specific application server for RichFaces. Any container that can run a Servlet is fine, such as Tomcat. Add the following dependencies in your `pom.xml` file **in addition** to your regular JSF 2.x dependency and you will be set. Rest of the dependencies are pulled automatically.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-components-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also note that you want to use a version of RichFaces greater than 4.x, 4.3.3.Final being the latest, as that is the version that has full support for JSF 2.0 and 2.1. For full JSF 2.2 support wait for RichFaces 5.0.x, which is in alpha at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I tried various ways but it is not working. By chance can anybody point to a tutorial/article which does this using tomcat and session beans. but not Java EE beans

Comment: What exactly is not working? Go to http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/docs for referance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a working setup with the dependencies that may be of interest. It's from a project running in production on Tomcat 6.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>richfaces-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2_12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2_12</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.11</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help; I tried various ways but it is not working. By chance can anybody point to a tutorial/article which does this using tomcat and session beans. but not Java EE beans